# Dart - Parse Nested Json Arrays

Tags: flutter, dart

Getting errors after trying to convert nested JSON data using dart's factory concept. 
Here I have two classes to handle the json data, but still getting this error:

> Exception has occurred.
>   _TypeError (type 'FormatException' is not a subtype of type 'Map')

Here is the code:

```dart
    class BodyResponse {
      final Map<String, dynamic> message;
      BodyResponse({
        this.message
      });
      factory BodyResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return BodyResponse(message: json['message']);
      }
    }

    class ErrorResponse {
      final BodyResponse body;
      final int status;
      final String contentType;
      final bool success;

      ErrorResponse({
        this.body, this.status, this.contentType, this.success
      });

      factory ErrorResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return ErrorResponse(
          body: BodyResponse.fromJson(json['body']),
          status: json['status'],
          contentType: json['content_type'],
          success: json['success']
        );
      }
    }

    ErrorResponse errors = ErrorResponse.fromJson("""
      {
        "body": {
          "message": "Some one has already taken this username(fooBar), please try again with a new username."
        },
        "status": 500,
        "content_type": "application\/json",
        "success": false
      }
    """);

    print(errors);
```

What could go wrong here?

Comment: The value you pass as an argument at `ErrorResponse errors = ErrorResponse.fromJson(...)` seems to be a string, while the function expects it to be a map (`Map<String, dynamic> json`).

Comment: @George but still there is no way to pass the JSON then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified most of your code here. Hope that this is what you tried to achieve.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class BodyResponse {
  final String message;
  BodyResponse({this.message});

  BodyResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
    message = json['message'];

  factory BodyResponse.fromString(String encodedJson) {
    return BodyResponse.fromJson(json.decode(encodedJson));
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "message": message,
  };

  String toString() => json.encode(this.toJson());

}

class ErrorResponse {
  final BodyResponse body;
  final int status;
  final String contentType;
  final bool success;

  ErrorResponse({this.body, this.status, this.contentType, this.success});

  ErrorResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
    body = BodyResponse.fromJson(json['body']),
    status = json['status'],
    contentType = json['content_type'],
    success = json['success'];

  factory ErrorResponse.fromString(String encodedJson) {
    return ErrorResponse.fromJson(json.decode(encodedJson));
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "body": body.toJson(),
    "status": status,
    "contentType": contentType,
    "success": success,
  };

  String toString() => json.encode(this.toJson());

}

void main() {
  ErrorResponse errors = ErrorResponse.fromString("""
      {
        "body": {
          "message": "Some one has already taken this username(fooBar), please try again with a new username."
        },
        "status": 500,
        "content_type": "application\/json",
        "success": false
      }
    """);
  print(errors);
}
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: You solution works just fine when i run it in a dart environment. But when i am trying to use this inside a catch block again it seems to break :( Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnOUe.png

Comment: I've tried with both `ErrorResponse.fromJson` and `ErrorResponse.fromString` method

Comment: Also, the JSON somehow getting an extra `{` at the end of the string! https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcp9G.png

Comment: @rakibtg you are trying to get the server error response from local Dart exception (`e`). I believe you should use the same `response.body` with `fromString` method instead.

Comment: Thanks George for your time. From my JS knowledge i was trying with this `try...catch` block: https://i.imgur.com/07BUPdg.png Do you think according to dart it is possible? :)

Comment: what you can do is declare `response` variable before the `try...catch` and assign its value in `try`. But you also need to know that `catch` only fires if there was a Dart error thrown, not when request returns an error code. Perhaps you should check the `statusCode` of your request to know whether the server returned an error or not.